# Is it possible to fit a binomial cumulative distribution with only three data points in R?

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, fitting

I have three data points (0,0), (30,0.1538), (60,0.4914).

Is it possible to fit a binomial cumulative distribution function only using these three points in R? If not, what sort of extra information do I need to fit such a distribution?

Thank you for your kind help.

edit: 
Basically the x-axis of the curve is the number of days, and the y-axis is the cumulative proportion of population infected during an epidemic. Thus, the point (0,0) illustrates that no one is infected in the beginning; the point (30, 0.1538) illustrates that at day 30, 15.38% of the population is infected; and the point (60, 0.4914) illustrates that at day 60, 49.14% of the population is infected. I am asked to provide a max likelihood estimate using binomial distribution and also to provide the CI of proportion infected at day 30 and 60. Much thanks for your kind help!

I tried to search for maximum likelihood estimation of binomial distribution parameters here: https://rpubs.com/felixmay/MLE, but it seems it is not really relevant to my scenario where my data at day 30 and day 60 are dependent and cumulative in nature.

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing what these "data points"  mean. Could you tell us?  Would they be points intended to lie on the graph of the CDF?  If so, then no Binomial CDF will fit, because the value of *every* Binomial CDF at zero is strictly positive: it represents the chance of a zero count.

Comment: Basically the x-axis of the curve is the number of days, and the y-axis is the cumulative proportion of population infected during an epidemic. Thus, the point (0,0) illustrates that no one is infected in the beginning; the point (30, 0.1538) illustrates that at day 30, 15.38% of the population is infected; and the point (60, 0.4914) illustrates that at day 60, 49.14% of the population is infected. I am asked to provide a max likelihood estimate using binomial distribution and also to provide the CI of proportion infected at day 30 and 60. Much thanks for your kind help!

Comment: As I pointed out, your data will not be correctly modeled by the CDF of a binomial distribution.  It is conceivable that the *counts* (not the proportions!) will have binomial distributions and 30 and 60 days, *but those counts will be strongly dependent,* because (presumably) anyone infected at 30 days is also infected at 60--depending on how you define "infected."  If you could edit your post to include useful information about your data and the problem you are trying to solve, users will be able to offer suitable suggestions.

Comment: If I am able to produce the counts instead of proportion at days 0, 30 and 60, can a Binomial Distribution be fit? Say, at day 0, 0 out of the entire population is infected; at day 30, 30 out of a sample of 195 are infected, and at day 60, 86 out of 175 are infected. You are right in pointing out that the counts of infected at day 60 will strongly depend on the counts at day 30, as the infection lasts very long. Does this mean that a binomial distribution can never be fit?

Comment: If you can produce counts as well as the proportions, you can fit Binomial distributions to the results at 30 days and at 60 days--but that's not going to provide any enlightenment or tell you anything you don't already know.  In particular, it will be useless for making inferences about proportions at any other times.  For that, you need to posit a model of progress of infection.

Comment: If it might be of some use, I found that a one-parameter Rayleigh cumulative distribution function "1.0 - exp(-(x^2)/(2.0*a^2))" with parameter a = -5.1643455202629696E+01 fit the data well.

Comment: I understand your point where fitting a Binomoal Distribution will not provide extra information. However, if a binomial distribution has to be fit, what will be the R codes? I think I would still like to compare the results generated from a binomial distribution and the Rayleigh cumulative distribution. I tried to search for maximum likelihood estimation of binomial distribution parameters here: https://rpubs.com/felixmay/MLE, but it seems it is not really relevant to my scenario where my data at day 30 and day 60 are dependent and cumulative in nature. Thank you once again.

Comment: Please [merge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts - [account1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/239629/jackson) and [account2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/239781/jackson)